# How to ask multiple follow-up questions

Tags: discussion, comments, editing

Fairly lengthy answers (such as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51/78) or [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1784/78)) are wont to invite multiple follow-up questions by the same person.  My question is, what's the best way to ask multiple follow-up questions?

It seems cumbersome (to me) to ask them all in one comment (or several comments, if you run out of space).  Plus, the resulting knowledge may be "lost" in the comments, out-of-sight from other users.

The office worker in me wants to insert the follow-up questions inline with the original answer, and have the answerer edit them out when addressing them.  This way, the original answer is supplemented with the information that everyone can easily see.  For example:

> ...blah blah blah, here's some fairly involved explanation about the question asked...
>
> > **Follow-up 1: Can you expand on...?**
>
> ...blah blah blah, other linguists think that blah blah blah...
>
> > **Follow-up 2: Can you provide a reference to this research?**
>
> ...more explanation...
>
> > **Follow-up 3: Is this even used in modern Japanese any more?**

---

My gut tells me that one is expected to just use comments, and that this type of inline editing would not fly with the SE model.

Comment: Good question. I think the UI encourages putting small clarifying followups in comments and anything larger in a new seperate question, but that doesn’t neccesarily mean it’s the right answer. I’d also be interested to hear what @l'électeur thinks (as someone who I believe dislikes the comment model).